# How to add datagrid to ASP.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, datagrid

I want to add a datagrid to my ASP.net web application.  Is it possible to do this without recreating my project as a Silverlight project?  If so, how do I do it?

I only see the option to add a DataList in my toolbox and no option at all for a DataGrid.  I'm also not sure how to include a library in my project, if it is even possible to do this (this is my first time working with VB.NET so it's all a little confusing still).  In C, C++, Java it's so easy!  Or do I even need to use the SilverLight library at all?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous versions of .NET, a tabled list of records was referred to as a datagrid.  In .NET 4 (Visual Studio 2010), it is now called a [gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and will be available in the Toolbox.

Also, there isn't any need to recreate your project as a Silverlight project.  You can use gridviews in ASP.NET Web Applications.

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't find this information anywhere!